# it returns "null" when there is two value but it return value when there is single value in foreach loop in laravel

Tags: laravel, foreach, conditional-statements, where-clause

I want to return only one punch. i know there is 3 punch between this condition. I use it in a foreach loop (the loop is for each employee "$item"). but it returns "null". if there would only one punch then it works fine. but it return "null" when there is more then one punch. can anybody help me pls??

```php
    $nearest_entry = $punches->where('employee_id',$item->employee_id)
                             ->where('attendance_datetime','>=',$min_entry_time)
                             ->where('attendance_datetime','<=',$max_entry_time);
                             ->all(); 
    $nearest_entry_date = $nearest_entry->first();  
    dd($nearest_entry);
```

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: share your code. Edit question and add the code.

Comment: It's much preferred if you share your code as text within your answer instead of as a screenshot. This enables people to copy and paste your code so they can test it.